# Trouble getting Backbone.js view event to fire

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

It appears as though the following code is getting inside `initialize` but my event doesn't appear to be firing.

What am I missing here?

```
var index = (function ($, window, document) {

    var methods = {};

    methods = {
            init: function () {

            },

            getView: Backbone.View.extend({
              el: $('.settings'), 

              events: { 
                 'click .settings': 'addUl'
              },

              initialize: function () {
                  console.log('init');
              },

              render: function () {
              },

              addUl: function () { 
                console.log('addUI');
                this.el.append("<ul> <li>hello world </li> </ul>");
              }
            })
    };

    return methods;   } (jQuery, window, document));
```

`var stuff = new index.getView();`

Link to the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aziyuj/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space in `'click .settings'`

Comment: That worked, but why in the documentation is it written `click .blah` http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents

Comment: Good question, I'm beginning to suspect that my comment may be a side effect and not a proper solution. When I get some time I'll look into it further unless someone else answers.

Answer (score 3):

Actually remove .settings entirely.

'click .settings' is registering a click handler for a *descendant* of this.el that matches '.settings'.

In your example you want to register an event on this.el directly so you don't need the descendant selector.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that it is your view element (`$el`) that has the `settings` class and not a child.

`click .settings` tells backbone to bind a "click" event on the `$el` for any children that have `.settings`. However, because, it is `$el` which has the class `settings` the binding never match.

This is why when you remove `.settings` it works, because you say "any 'click' on $el"

The reason the documentation says `click .blah` is because it assumes that the html element(s) with the `class='blah'` are children of the `$el` element.

Hope this help.